# Can i disable a trigger inside a trigger in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have 2 triggers and two tables.
One(trigger) is to insert inside one column in the other table when a row in first table is inserted, the other one prevent insert and update in that column.
I want to know if there is a way i can disable the second trigger that prevents the insert/update during the execution of first trigger.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Did you find any error?

Comment: when i write "alter trigger name_of_trigger disable" inside of a trigger i shows me i cant do that inside a trigger. displaying a syntax error below "alter"

Comment: a Alter trigger is a DDL and you have to use  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER triggername DISABLE' if you want to execute a DDL from a PL/SQL code. try using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Oracle is not executing it inside the trigger @hkandpal. Oracle just jumps that line.

Comment: The DDL cannot be executed within the scope of a single DML transaction: you can't embed it inside a trigger that is inherently a part of the DML. You would have to execute the DDL first, separately, so that the trigger is disabled for all transactions, then execute your DML, commit, and then re-enable the trigger. It would be simpler to include logic in the second trigger to determine when it should and should not allow insert/update.

Comment: Why do you use a trigger to prevent insert and update of a column? Put all logic into one trigger or even better use a PL/SQL Procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understood the question. See if it helps.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table test_2 (id number);

Table created.
```

A trigger on `test_2` which prevents inserts:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg2
  2    before insert or update on test_2
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not allowed');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> insert into test_2 (id) values (1);
insert into test_2 (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Not allowed
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG2", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG2'
```

Yes, it works.

---

Now, a trigger on `test` which is supposed to a) disable `trg2` trigger and b) insert value into `test_2`. A straightforward code would then be

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg1
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    execute immediate 'alter trigger trg2 disable';
  6    insert into test_2 (id) values (:new.id);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);
insert into test (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG1", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG1'
```

Aha. Can't `COMMIT` in a trigger. Where is it? In dynamic SQL's `alter trigger` - it is a DDL and it implicitly commits. How to "fix" it? Make it (a trigger) an autonomous transaction:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg1
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  6  begin
  7    execute immediate 'alter trigger trg2 disable';
  8    insert into test_2 (id) values (:new.id);
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);
insert into test (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG1", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG1'
```

That's another error; it says that - if we have an autonomous transaction - we have to either commit or roll back. Let's commit (because that's probably what you'd want to do):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg1
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  6  begin
  7    execute immediate 'alter trigger trg2 disable';
  8    insert into test_2 (id) values (:new.id);
  9    commit;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID
----------
       100

SQL> select * from test_2;

        ID
----------
       100

SQL>
```

---

Right; now it *works*.

I suggest you re-read comments posted below your question, see this example and choose what to do.

Comment: PERFECT MAN, THANK U SO MUCH.