# Trigger not disabling

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER azuriranje
AFTER UPDATE OF napomena
ON otpremnica
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER zabranjeno DISABLE';
UPDATE stavkaotpremnice
SET napomena =:NEW.napomena
WHERE brojotpremnice =:NEW.brojotpremnice;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER zabranjeno ENABLE';
END;
```

Does anyone knows why the trigger "zabranjeno" is not disabling before the update?

Comment: you can't do ddl like that in a trigger.  Why would you want to do that?  If you need to enable/disable create a script.

Comment: You cannot put DDL commands in the middle of a DML transaction, as they force an implicit commit. You would need to disable the other trigger separately, before making any updates to napomena, then re-enable it separately after you commit your changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is at least 3rd question you posted, related to the same problem. I answered one of them ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535199/can-i-disable-a-trigger-inside-a-trigger-in-oracle)), so - what's the point in asking thet same question all over again?

Anyway: reading what you posted (as questions or comments), I'd say that you're doing it **completely wrong**. Here's why:

- you have two tables: `otpremnica` and `stavkaotpremnice`
- you don't want to allow users to update `napomena` column in `stavkaotpremnice` and, therefore, created the `zabranjeno` trigger on that table
- at the same time, trigger `azuriranje` on table otpremnica should

  - disable trigger `zabranjeno`
  - set `stavkaotpremnice.napomena = otpremnica.napomena` for that `brojotpremnice`, for **all rows** in `stavkaotpremnice`
  - enable trigger `zabranjeno`

The last bullet ("at the same time ...") shows why this is wrong. Your data model violates the 3rd normal form; there's no point & no sense in keeping the same `napomena` value in both master (`otpremnica`) and detail (`stavkaotpremnice`) tables.

If you want to show (display) `napomena` with all rows in `stavkaotpremnice`, then join those tables, e.g.

```
select o.brojotpremnice,
       s.brojstavke,
       s.nazivstavke,
       o.napomena              --> here's your NAPOMENA
from otpremnica o join stavkaotpremnice s on s.brojotpremnice = o.brojotpremnice
where ...
```

Finally, what's the point of having the `napomena` column in `stavkaotpremnice` if you won't allow users to enter any note they find appropriate?

---

Therefore, to cut a long story short, to solve your nightmare, modify data model:

- remove `napomena` from `stavkaotpremnice`
- drop both `zabranjeno` and `azuriranje` triggers
- fetch `napomena` from `otpremnica` table, whenever needed

  - alternatively, create a **view** using the query I posted above